# in regex how to match patterns of alphanumeric string with space or punctuation before/after them

Tags: python, regex

I have input like this

```
txt='.A3 S3- D4(SPACE) D5/ E9R E0&'
```

How can I extract all patterns matching 1 letter + 1 number. It's ok to have punctuation (except&) or space before or after or both, but another letter before or after is not allowed.

The intended matches are:

```
['A3', 'S3', 'D4', 'D5']
```

E9R will not be returned as it contains a letter after E9. 
E0& will not be return as it contains &

```
import re
re.findall('[a-z]{2,3}[0-9]{1,3}',txt)
```

Comment: You can use word boundaries together with lookarounds: [`\b(?<!&)[A-Z]\d{1,3}\b(?!&)`](https://regex101.com/r/TXlDRN/1)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may use

```
re.findall(r'(?<![a-z0-9&])[a-z][0-9](?![a-z0-9&])', s, re.I)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ySu4ff/1)

**Details**

- `(?<![a-z0-9&])` - a location that is not immediately preceded with an ASCII letter, digit or `&`
- `[a-z]` - an ASCII letter (note that `re.I` makes the pattern case insensitive)
- `[0-9]` - an ASCII digit
- `(?![a-z0-9&])` - a location that is not immediately followed with an ASCII letter, digit or `&`.

[Python demo](https://ideone.com/omfZqY):

```
import re
rx = r"(?<![a-z0-9&])[a-z][0-9](?![a-z0-9&])"
s = ".A3 S3- D4(SPACE) D5/ E9R E0&"
print(re.findall(rx, s, re.I))
# => ['A3', 'S3', 'D4', 'D5']
```

Comment: if i need to replace these patterns with a random number corresponding to each pattern, such as ".A3 B4/ A3! B4+ C5_" will become ['1', '4','1','4']  where 1 and 4 are random number each corresponding to A3 and B4, is that achievable with re.sub? Thanks!

Comment: @santoku Yes, you may use `re.sub(rx, lambda x: generate_randomvalue_method(x.group()), s, flags=re.I)`